# While using setInterval to load a list in angular 4 the same loadlist function firing when clicking other links also

Tags: javascript, angular

In our angular 4 application, I have to load a grid with in a specified time. I have used setInterval for the same. Please see the below code snippet used.

interval: any;

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.loadList();

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {  

        this.loadList();

    }, 30000);
```

The loadList executes every 30 seconds even after moving to another link. I have to load the list if the user is on the correct page. Now its firing always. How to resolve the same?

Anyone please help to resolve the same.

Comment: Do you only want it to run 1 time? If so, setTimeout  instead of setInterval would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that interval only on this component, you can implement the built in OnDestroy interface and use the method ngOnDestroy like below:

```
import {OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
export class yourComponent implements OnDestroy {

   ngOnDestroy(){
     clearInterval(this.interval);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the interval listener on `ngOnDestroy` (when you navigate out of that page component) and re-attach it when that page is loaded again.

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
   clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```